# How much cash to take to Tenerife all-inclusive for a week?

Tags: money, tenerife

In a couple of months we'll be going on a week-long all-inclusive holiday in Tenerife.  Although advertised as "leave your wallet at home", from past experiences I know this is never that simple.

I have previously been on an all-inclusive in Mexico and Turkey - and in both cases  ended up giving extra tips in the resorts as well as going to some activities outside the resorts.  All of this, of course, costs extra.

I'm not sure what (if anything) we'll do outside the resort, but I'm guessing at a minimum I should have some cash for some extra tips and transport from the resort to the nearest town. Anything else?

Even if the resort has currency exchange services, the rate is probably not the best, so better to have Euro with me, I suppose.

Naturally, I'll have credit card and bank card to withdraw cash from ATMs if needed - however how much cash should I bring with me?  The are two adults and three children under 6. If it matters, we're going from the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, at least 20 euros per day, if possible in 5 euros bills.

Mostly for tips to the staff.